# Find out which functions were inlined

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, inline

When compiling C++ with GCC 4.4 or MSVC is it possible to get the compiler to emit messages when a function is inlined?

Comment: Good question but I'm curious as to your motives.

Comment: I re-structured code moving a lot of code from header  to cpp files and now it runs slower. I want to see if there is difference in the number of functions inlining

Comment: How are you building?  Release or Debug?  What are you specifying for /OPT for Visual Studio?

Comment: Using GCC -O3 -march=native -DNDEBUG -msse2 -std=c++0x

Comment: FWIW, it might be worth giving `-O2` a try too. I hear it can go either way depending on the nature of the code... (a nature which changed significantly)

Comment: It pretty much gave identical performance to O3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With g++, I don't think you can make g++ report that, but you can examine the resulting binary with any tool that shows symbols, `nm` for example:

```
#include <iostream>
struct T {
        void print() const;
};
void T::print() const { std::cout << " test\n" ; }
int main()
{
        T t;
        t.print();
}

~ $ g++ -O3  -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o test test.cc
~ $ nm test | grep print
0000000000400800 t _GLOBAL__I__ZNK1T5printEv
0000000000400830 T _ZNK1T5printEv
```

vs

```
#include <iostream>
struct T {
        void print() const { std::cout << " test\n" ; }
};
int main()
{
        T t;
        t.print();
}
~ $ g++ -O3  -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o test test.cc
~ $ nm test | grep print
```

(no output from nm in the second case)

EDIT:
Also, profilers may be of use. gprof shows, on these two examples:

```
0.00      0.00     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  global constructors keyed to _ZNK1T5printEv
0.00      0.00     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  T::print() const
```

vs. just

```
0.00      0.00     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  global constructors keyed to main
```

Comment: FWIW, depending on how the functions are used, the compiler may inline some instances and not others. If the program is sufficiently large, something more sophisticated would be necessary.

Comment: Indeed. I wonder if any profilers report something like that (gprof doesn't appear to). Could be a useful little tool to write.

Comment: Thanks. I can see differences in the compiled binaries. The header only version seems to have inlined more functions. I ran on gprof before (compiled with -pg) and couldn't much differences between the two. I just ran the programs on callgrind and header only version appears to have inlined at lot of functions as they don't show up in callgrinds output.